# SQLAlchemy Filtering on Third Degree Relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQL alchemy as part of a budgeting tool with the following classes. I'm trying to filter Transactions by whether they are or not in a Budget. For that to occur a Transaction must be in a Category that has a Budget Item and the Transaction Date must fall within the Budget's Start and End Dates associated to that Budget Item. I can achieve this with the is_in_budget Transaction property. The issues with my approach are that the property will become slow as more Transactions and Budget Items are added, and that I cannot filter by the property to either true or false. Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing? My goal is to query this property with a filter .filter(Transaction.is_in_budget==True)

```py
    class Budget(Base):
        __tablename__ = "budget"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        date_start = Column(Date)
        date_end = Column(Date)
        is_current = Column(Boolean)
        budget_items = relationship("BudgetItem", back_populates="budget")
    
    
    class BudgetItem(Base):
        __tablename__ = "budgetItem"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        budget_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("budget.id"), nullable=False)
        budget = relationship("Budget", back_populates = "budget_items")
        category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category.id"), nullable=False)
        category = relationship("Category", back_populates= "budget_items")
        amount = Column(Float)
    
    class Category(Base):
        __tablename__ = "category"
    
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String, nullable=False)
        classification = Column(String, nullable=False)
        category_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(
            "category_type.id"), default=1)
        category_type = relationship("CategoryType", back_populates="categories")
        transactions = relationship(
            "Transaction", back_populates="category", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
        saving = relationship("Saving", back_populates="category",
                              cascade="all, delete-orphan")
        budget_items = relationship(
            "BudgetItem", back_populates="category", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    
    class Transaction(Base):
        __tablename__ = "transaction"
    
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        description = Column(String, nullable=True)
        amount = Column(Float, nullable=False)
        account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("account.id"), nullable=False)
        account = relationship("Account", back_populates="transactions")
        date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
        note = Column(String)
        category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category.id"), nullable=False)
        category = relationship("Category", back_populates="transactions")
        is_budget = Column(Boolean)
        is_savings = Column(Boolean)
        is_temporary = Column(Boolean)
        loan_payment = relationship("LoanPayment", back_populates="transaction")
    
        @property
        def is_in_budget(self):
            if self.is_budget:
                for budget_item in self.category.budget_items:
                    if self.date >= budget_item.budget.date_start and self.date <= budget_item.budget.date_end:
                        return True
                return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query for transactions without a budget like this:

```
session.query(Transaction).filter(Budget.is(None)).all()
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case the Category to Budget Item relationship is one to many so I need to check whether the transaction date falls within the one of the Budgets start and end dates.

Comment: You can simply add filter options like this:
session.query(Transaction).filter(Transaction.date.between(Budget.start, Budget.end)).filter(Budget.is(None)).all()

Comment: These do half the job.  They return the transactions that fall in a Budget Date Range. How about returning the Transactions that don't fall inside a Budge Date Range. I tried negating the filter but because you have a one to many from Category to Budget Items you need to first check if the Category has any Budget Items join(Category).filter(~Category.budget_items.any()) Then from if the Transaction date is in the Budget date range join(Category).join(BudgetItem).join(Budget).filter(~Transaction.date.between(Budget.start, Budget.end)) but no luck.